# Functional Test Runs in Anypoint but not IntelliJ

Tags: mule

I have the following test case

```
public class TestTwo extends FunctionalTestCase {

    @Override
    protected String getConfigResources() {
        return "mule-conf.xml";
    }

    @Test
    public void testClient2PersonMigration() throws Exception {

        MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
        String payload = "someTextxxxx";
        Map<String, Object> messageProperties = null;
        MuleMessage result = client.send("vm://test", payload, messageProperties); //URL, Payload, MessageProperties

        assertNotNull(result);
        assertNull(result.getExceptionPayload());
        assertFalse(result.getPayload() instanceof NullPayload);
        assertEquals("Pass", result.getPayloadAsString()); //if I comment this it works
    }
}
```

And config XML file

```
  <flow name="simplejunittestFlow1" doc:name="simplejunittestFlow1">
        <inbound-endpoint address="vm://test" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="Generic"/>
        <expression-transformer expression="#['Fail']"/>
        <flow-ref name="simplejunittestFlow2" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    </flow>
    <sub-flow name="simplejunittestFlow2" doc:name="simplejunittestFlow2">
        <expression-transformer expression="#['Pass']"/>
    </sub-flow>
```

This test runs and passes in Anypoint Studio using Mule 3.3 but when using IntellIj with Mule 3.2 it complains of the following error

> Caused by: org.mule.api.transport.NoReceiverForEndpointException:
>   There is no receiver registered on connector
>   "connector.VM.mule.default" for endpointUri vm://test

Anyone have any idea of indication why the test runs and passes fine in Anypoint but fails to run in IntelliJ?

Comment: Are `mule-conf.xml` is on the classpath of your IntelliJ project?

Comment: Also I'm not sure you deserve our attention because you asked a similar question ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/34634023/387927 ) and deleted it while we were in the process of solving it, without any explanation why. If you solved the other problem, post your fix as an accepted answer, so it helps other people facing the same problem. Simply deleting your question while it has started to receive attention is plain rude.

Comment: Yes mule-conf.xml is in the src/main/app folder.

Comment: And sorry I deleted it simply because I had no access to that code anymore and could not provide a effective response to your question.

Comment: Mmmh OK, thanks for the context, although your current question looks very similar.

Comment: Is `src/main/app` in your project's POM `build/resources` section?

Comment: No it wasn't, I added it but still getting the same error message. Could it be an issue with Mule 3.2?

Comment: I doubt it, you're not doing anything extraordinary nor recent. This was working in 3.2 just fine. If you add a `@Test` method in `TestTwo` that loads `mule-conf.xml` from the classpath, does it work?

Comment: Like this? `@Test
    public void FunctionalTestAttempt2() {
        try {
            SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder builder = new SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder("./src/main/app/mule-conf.xml");
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`

Comment: No, this is not loading from the classpath but from a file path. Use: `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("mule-conf.xml")` If this gets `null`, the config is not on the classpath.